# Even out quantity of rows with a certain pair

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a pandas data frame that looks something like this:

```
  data  |  Flag  |  Set
-----------------------------
  0     |  True  |  A
  30    |  True  |  A
  -1    |  False |  A
  20    |  True  |  B
  5     |  False |  B
  19    |  False |  B
  7     |  False |  C
  8     |  False |  c
```

How can I (elegantly) drop rows in such a way that, for each set, there is an equal number of `True` and `False` `Flag`s? The output would look something like this

```
  data  |  Flag  |  Set
-----------------------------
  0     |  True  |  A
  -1    |  False |  A
  20    |  True  |  B
  5     |  False |  B
```

as for `A`, there is one false flag, for `B` there is one true flag, and for `C` there are zero true flags. I know how to brute force this, but I feel like there's some elegant way that I don't know about.

Comment: Would you only want one `True` and one `False` per set or if you had much more data, you would want 10 `True` and 10 `False` for a set if there were for example 11 `False` and `10` True?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get counts of `Flag`s per `Set` by [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), filter out rows with `0` - it means unique `True` or `False` values and get minimal value to dictionary `d`:

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Set'], df['Flag'])
d = df1[df1.ne(0).all(axis=1)].min(axis=1).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': 1, 'B': 1}
```

Then filter rows by `Set` column and keys of dictionary and then use [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) per groups by this `dict` :

```
df1 = (df[df['Set'].isin(d.keys())]
           .groupby(['Set', 'Flag'], group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda x: x.head(d[x.name[0]])))
print (df1)
   data   Flag Set
2    -1  False   A
0     0   True   A
4     5  False   B
3    20   True   B
```

EDIT: For verify solution for return if there are 2 times `True` and `False` per Set `A`:

```
print (df)
   data   Flag Set
0     0   True   A
1     8   True   A
2    30   True   A
3    -1  False   A
4   -14  False   A
5    20   True   B
6     5  False   B
7    19  False   B
8     7  False   C
9     8  False   c


df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Set'], df['Flag'])
d = df1[df1.ne(0).all(axis=1)].min(axis=1).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': 2, 'B': 1}

df1 = (df[df['Set'].isin(d.keys())]
           .groupby(['Set', 'Flag'], group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda x: x.head(d[x.name[0]])))
print (df1)
   data   Flag Set
3    -1  False   A
4   -14  False   A
0     0   True   A
1     8   True   A
6     5  False   B
5    20   True   B
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I came up with an easy-to-understand, concise solution:

1. Simply get the `.cumcount()` grouped by `set` and `flag`
2. Check if a group of `set` and the `cumcount` result above (`cc` below in the code) is duplicated. If a group contains no duplicates, then that means it needs to be removed.

---

```
In[1]: 
    data   Flag Set
0      0   True   A
1      8   True   A
2     30   True   A
3      0   True   A
4      8   True   A
5     30   True   A
6     -1  False   A
7    -14  False   A
8     -1  False   A
9    -14  False   A
10    20   True   B
11     5  False   B
12    19  False   B
13     7  False   C
14     8  False   c
```

---

EDIT 2: Per @Jezrael , I could simplify the below three lines of code further to:

```
df = (df[df.assign(cc = df.groupby(['Set', 'Flag'])
           .cumcount()).duplicated(['Set','cc'], keep=False)])
```

Further breakdown of code below.

---

```
df['cc'] = df.groupby(['Set', 'Flag']).cumcount()
s = df.duplicated(['Set','cc'], keep=False)
df = df[s].drop('cc', axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
    data   Flag Set
0      0   True   A
1      8   True   A
2     30   True   A
3      0   True   A
6     -1  False   A
7    -14  False   A
8     -1  False   A
9    -14  False   A
10    20   True   B
11     5  False   B
```

Prior to dropping, this is how the data would look:

```
df['cc'] = df.groupby(['Set', 'Flag']).cumcount()
df['s'] = df.duplicated(['Set','cc'], keep=False)
# df = df[df['s']].drop('cc', axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
    data   Flag Set  cc      s
0      0   True   A   0   True
1      8   True   A   1   True
2     30   True   A   2   True
3      0   True   A   3   True
4      8   True   A   4  False
5     30   True   A   5  False
6     -1  False   A   0   True
7    -14  False   A   1   True
8     -1  False   A   2   True
9    -14  False   A   3   True
10    20   True   B   0   True
11     5  False   B   0   True
12    19  False   B   1  False
13     7  False   C   0  False
14     8  False   c   0  False
```

Then, the `False` rows in column `s` are dropped with `df = df[df['s']]`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael I missed a row in the copy/paste

Comment: So it return if 2 times `True` or `False` per group?

Comment: Maybe I implemented it poorly, but this seems to be removing more rows than I would expect. I might have, say, 30 True and 25 False for a particular group

Comment: Got it @Warlax56 ,  I just asked that question in the comments. I will remove this answer then.

Comment: No problem man, I appreciate it, still learned a lot from it!

Comment: @Warlax56 if you're interested, I have updated my solution although Jezrael's answer is a little bit more concise.

Comment: @Warlax56 not trying to compete for a solution, but I thought of a simpler solution in the shower and it made sense to change my answer.

Comment: Simpliest is `df = df[df.assign(cc = df.groupby(['Set', 'Flag']).cumcount()).duplicated(['Set','cc'], keep=False)]`

Comment: I was trying to simplify it even more, but I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a possible solution consisting of 3 steps:

- Removing all sets that don't have true and false flags (here C)
- Counting the number of rows that are wanted for each set-flag combination
- Removing all rows that are over that number of counted rows

This yield the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"data":[0, 30, -1, 20, 5, 19, 7, 8],
                        "Flag":[True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False],
                        "Set":["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"]})


# 1. removing sets with only one of both flags
reducer = df.groupby("Set")["Flag"].transform("nunique") > 1
df_reduced = df.loc[reducer]

# 2. counting the minimum number of rows per set
counts = df_reduced.groupby(["Set", "Flag"]).count().groupby("Set").min()

# 3. reducing each set and flag to the minumum number of rows
df_equal = df_reduced.groupby(["Set", "Flag"]) \
            .apply(lambda x: x.head(counts.loc[x["Set"].values[0]][0])) \
            .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Jezrael's answer sure is fancy, but I do think this is a good balance between elegance and simplicity